# Jquery / HTML5? Possibly canvas? line manipulation

Tags: jquery, html, canvas

A little problem I have...

Imagine a ractangle say 500 x 250. (easy bit)

Within the rectangle there is a line accross the whole width.

I would like the user to be able to drag this line up and down within the rectangle. (could be done quite easily with a jqueryui draggable)

I would also like the user to be able to click on the line to split it, and then have two lines (This is where I am stuck). Also a method to rejoin the two lines together.

I don't really no where to start with this, any ideas of where I should be looking, or for a suitable plugin that allows this?

Thanks
Matt

Comment: Can you describe what you mean by "split it"

Comment: one line, click on it, you now have two lines.

Comment: two horizontal lines spanning the width, one above the other, or one horizontal line broken at the point where you want to split it?

Comment: one horizontal line broken at the point where you want to split it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/Ttp4g/) using HTML5 Canvas and the KineticJS framework.

At the beginning, there is only one horizontal line and after you clicked it once, there are two lines remaining, split exactly where the user clicked.

Here is the code:

```
var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
    container: 'container'
});

var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();

var rect = new Kinetic.Rect({
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    width: 500,
    height: 250,
    fill: 'red'
});
layer.add(rect);

var line = new Kinetic.Rect({
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    width: 500,
    height: 2,
    fill: 'black',
    draggable: true,
    dragBoundFunc: function (pos) {
        return {
            x: this.getAbsolutePosition().x,
            y: pos.y
        };
    }
});
layer.add(line);
stage.add(layer);
stage.draw();

line.on('click', function(e){
    var y = line.getY();
    line.destroy();
    var line1 = new Kinetic.Rect({
        x: 0,
        y: y,
        width: e.x,
        height: 2,
        fill: 'black',
        draggable: true,
        dragBoundFunc: function (pos) {
            return {
                x: this.getAbsolutePosition().x,
                y: pos.y
            };
        }
    });

    var line2 = new Kinetic.Rect({
        x: e.x,
        y: y,
        width: stage.getWidth()-e.x,
        height: 2,
        fill: 'black',
        draggable: true,
        dragBoundFunc: function (pos) {
            return {
                x: this.getAbsolutePosition().x,
                y: pos.y
            };
        }
    });
    layer.add(line1);
    layer.add(line2);
    stage.add(layer);
    stage.draw();
});
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for that, but it doesn't seem to show anything? am I missing something?

Comment: Doesn't it show anything at all or only the line, because the line is on the very top of the red rectangle (black, a little hard to see ;))

Comment: Ok, I got it - browser issue, this doesn't seem to work in the latest versions. Thanks for your help.